# Как сделать рабочую область C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-n-drop

Делаю программу по учебе и мне требуется сделать конструктор php файла. Пытаюсь сделать программу на C# Winforms и хочу реализовать drag-n-drop интерфейс, позволяющий перетаскивать модули на рабочую область. Из этой области можно будет обращаться к модулям и их настраивать.
Примерный макет программы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я примерно разобрался как сделать drag-n-drop функционал, но не знаю как сделать рабочую область, или просто панель использовать или что-то специализированное, ведь потом по области нужно собирать php файл.
 
Буду благодарен любым советам

Comment: Что за рабочая область? Текстовый редактор нужен? TextBox/RichTextBox пробовали? А почему винформы? На WPF+MVVM такие ООП-штуки проще делаются.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за совет, мне нужно сделать конструктор аналогичный Tilda. Не текстовый редактор

Comment: То, что вы хотите, зовется MDI. Берите любой готовый инструмент и вперед.

Comment: Но ведь php файл это текст

Comment: @aepot мне по заданию нужно это сделать через модули, например: абзац текста. Я переношу модуль на раб.область и через параметры модуля указываю текст. А потом по всей рабочей области собираю файл конвертируя модули в текст с указанными параметрами

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за совет